# plot grid of bar charts or wrap bar chart using python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create horizontal bar chart using python, but there are too many categories
like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4',
     'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9',
     'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13', 'c14',
     'c15', 'c16', 'c17', 'c18', 'c19',
     'c20', 'c21', 'c22', 'c23', 'c24',
     'c25', 'c26', 'c27', 'c28', 'c29']
    
 y = [9556, 9318, 9308, 2556, 2424, 1812, 1624, 1468, 1398, 1344, 1200,
    1056, 888, 732, 732, 704, 684, 680, 666, 660, 636, 624,
    576, 552, 544, 532, 468, 448, 448, 436]
    
 plt.barh(new_x, new_y)
```

[image]
The above code is only a part of the categories, in fact, the number of my categories is more than 200.
**I want to cut into two subplots to present,
[like this](https://www.pewforum.org/2022/03/02/how-indians-view-gender-roles-in-families-and-society/)**

[image]

**Is there any way to plot the above graph in python?**

Comment: Create [two subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) with `sharex=True` to ensure both are scaled correctly

Comment: You can use `ax1.margins(y=0.01)` to reduce the whitespace on the top and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Use an index to split your data, and a vertical subplot to plot you data.
E.g. something like this:

```
split = len(x) // 2
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=False, figsize=(10, 8))


x = ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4',
     'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9',
     'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13', 'c14',
     'c15', 'c16', 'c17', 'c18', 'c19',
     'c20', 'c21', 'c22', 'c23', 'c24',
     'c25', 'c26', 'c27', 'c28', 'c29']
    
y = [9556, 9318, 9308, 2556, 2424, 1812, 1624, 1468, 1398, 1344, 1200,
1056, 888, 732, 732, 704, 684, 680, 666, 660, 636, 624,
576, 552, 544, 532, 468, 448, 448, 436]

ax1.barh(x[0:split], y[0:split])
ax2.barh(x[split:], y[split:])
```

Result:
[image]

Tweak the plot further to get your plots the same as your example.